# Angular Dart $scope.$on functionality is not working

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to call a destroy function when the dart-angular controller are removed.

This is the angular.js solution.

```javascript
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
       alert("destroy");
});
```

My try in Dart

```dart
class TestController...

TestController(Scope $scope){
    $scope.$on("$destroy",(){
            print("destroy");
    });
}
```

and this is the Error Code

```
Error!
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'destroy'
```

`$destroy or destroy` literal is not working. Any Idea?

Comment: Try using: `$scope.$on(r'$destroy', () {` (using `r`)

Comment: Yes that works as well. Thank you very much in deep.

Comment: I've post an answer to give better visibility to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a better way

```dart
class TestConroller implements NgDetachAware {
  void detach() {
    alert("destroy");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Frank if the answer worked for you you can omit the comment and instead accept the answer - check the checkmark below the up/downvote counter - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `$on` must be a pattern.
You must declare it using the `r` prefix.

```dart
$scope.$on(r'$destroy', function() {
  alert("destroy");
});
```