# What's AngularDart Scope object used for

Tags: angularjs, dart, angularjs-scope, angular-dart

Sometimes I try to find some info about AngularDart and end up in AngularJs documentations/SO questions and posts...

So I keep coming across posts and answers that mention a `$scope` object in AngularJs. I'm not too sure what it's supposed to be used for, and I can't find too much information about it for AngularDart.

According to this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope it looks like it's used pretty much like a regular function in a component or an attribute with an Angular annotation.

For example in the documentation of AngularJs they show this :

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'World';

    $scope.sayHello = function() {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
    };
  }]);
```

which I think can be simply achieved in AngularDart by having a component a `username` field annotated with `@NgTwoWay` or `@NgAttr`. And for the method `sayHello()`, just have that method in the component.

So I see that there is an actual `scope` object in AngularDart (based on questions like this [Angular Dart $scope.$on functionality is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403654/angular-dart-scope-on-functionality-is-not-working)) but is it of any use?

Comment: Note that the best article I found was http://victorsavkin.com/post/86909839576/angulardart-1-0-for-angularjs-developers-introduction but I'm not sure it's still true, since 1.0.0 has just been released and this article is ~5 months old.

Comment: Victor Savkin wrote the original article 5 months ago (it was titled ANGULARDART FOR ANGULARJS DEVELOPERS). I'm prtty sure he updated it recently for Angular 1.0 and changed the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Angular.Dart for the last year or so, and I haven't found any use for the $scope variable in Angular.Dart.

In AngularJS, you can use the $scope for a couple of things - to discriminate between scopes when multiple HTML files are controlled by a single controller, and for third party component integration (the $scope.apply in the article you found from Victor Savkin). However, third party integration is now automatic. And you can no longer have more than one controller with Angular.Dart 1.0, it's all done with components, and the scope there is implicit and therefore hidden.

Additional, very dated info at the following location (search for Scope):
http://teropa.info/blog/2014/02/11/kicking-the-tires-on-angulardart.html